# How to know unfreed memory in a function?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-leaks, valgrind

I know one can use Valgrind to find memory leaks in the execution of a whole program. But now I want to trace unfreed memory during execution of a function. The function is just part of a program but it is quite complex and contains calls to other functions. The program is Valgrind clean.

Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: suggest adding language and compiler tags

Comment: we are not good at mind reading,  Post the code

Comment: @user3629249 It is a general question and not about specific code. To give a C example,  int main() { foo(); bar(); }. I want to know "After execution of foo(), is there unfreed memory allocated in foo(), assuming the whole program is leak-free, also assuming foo() is in a big complex library.

Answer (score 3):

If a program does not have any memory leaks, it means none of its functions has memory leaks. If you ran the program, verified that the function was executed for all relevant use-cases, and Valgrind didn't find any leaks, than the function couldn't have any leaks.

If you want to detect leaks in the function only, you simply write a unit test for it and run that under valgrind. That makes it easier to cover some cases that may be difficult to cover by using the outer program interface.

Of course valgrind is dynamic analysis, and can only check leaks that actually happen during the test run, so you have to take some care to get good coverage. It also suppresses leaks where there is still something that looks like valid pointer to the memory somewhere. This is because many libraries don't bother freeing memory at shutdown (and rightly so; the system has to clean it up anyway), but it might lead to a false negative occasionally. Static analysis would be better in this regards, but I don't know about any good one for this purpose—detecting invalid memory management statically is really hard (even Rust can prevent use-after-free reliably, but only most leaks, not all).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A user said a routine of our library periodically increased RSS (resident set size) of their app, resulting in possible out-of-memory. However, our library's memory allocator tracer reported no unfreed memory in this routine.  Both the app and our library are very complex and it is hard to separate out a unit test. So I what to have a valgrind tool to detect "memory leaks" (actually, unfreed memory, since there is no leaks in the app) in a user specified segment of code. Many profiling tools have APIs for users to only profile a segment of code. Hope valgrind can do it.